# Where to ask questions about database design

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question I need help with in regards to designing the layout of a database.

Where would I ask this?

Answer (score 8):

You can ask your question on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

From the [on topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page:

> - Data Modelling and database-design, including referential-integrity